# How to change the public IP address of Bind DNS server for a second level domain?

Tags: domain, ip, bind

My company is the Maintainer for at least one second level domain like example.com. The previous sysadmin created a GNU/Linux Bind9 DNS server running on a public IP address x.x.x.x which resolves "public" dns queries for that domain. 
Now we are migrating from one ISP to another and our public IP address will soon change in something like y.y.y.y. I think we will loose our DNS reachability. How can I avoid this? We also run a mail server inside our network and we don't want to loose mail server reachability.

How can I change the Bind9 DNS server IP? What's the technical procedure to do that? We are not Registrant but only Maintainers

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name server for your domain, you need to contact the domain registrar.  If you aren't sure who the registrar is for your domain, go to a site like http://www.whois.net and look up the domain -- the results will include information about the registrar.

Part of the information that your domain's registrar maintains about the domain is a list of name servers which have the authoritative data about your domain.  Most registrars allow you to update this information by logging in to their web site.

Note -- if you are changing your name server's IP address, it won't work to simply change the NS records in the zone data on your name server.  You need to change the name server data maintained by your domain registrar.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple NS records for a certain domain.

```
# dig NS +ans +short google.com
ns3.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
```

So you could prepare, and bring up the new DNS server in the new location as ns2.yourdomain.com and remove the first one whenever you have done the migration.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I will try this solution soon!

Comment: Setting you TTL down to an hour or so during the transition will help your changes propagate faster.  Set it back to a longer period like 1 day when you are done.